# Mapbox: Error setting property: icon-image [2] Branch labels must be numbers or strings

Tags: kotlin, mapbox-android

I'm trying to use the [match() Expression](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#match) from Mapbox's Android SDK 9.0.0 with a list of ids.  But I'm getting the following error at runtime:

> "Error setting property: icon-image [2] Branch labels must be numbers or strings."

I am coding in [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/).

To isolate the essence of the problem, I'm trying to pass match() an array of a *single* String element using the `arrayOf()` operator:

```
match(get(KEY_ID), literal(arrayOf("134")), appearanceIfSelected, appearanceIfNotSelected)
```

The code above didn't work though and gave the error above.  The following code that used `arrayListOf()` also failed:

```
match(get(KEY_ID), literal(arrayListOf(pois!!.first().id)), appearanceIfSelected, appearanceIfNotSelected)
```

`listOf()` also failed:

```
match(get(KEY_ID), literal(listOf(pois!!.first().id)), appearanceIfSelected, appearanceIfNotSelected)
```

Wrapping in [`array()`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#types-array) failed too:

```
match(get(KEY_ID), array(literal(listOf("134"))), appearanceIfSelected, appearanceIfNotSelected)
```

I have been wrapping in `literal()` because the following won't even compile:

```
match(get(KEY_ID), arrayOf("134"), appearanceIfSelected, appearanceIfNotSelected)
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I replaced `match()` with [`any()`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#any) and passed a variable number of arguments using the [`Kotlin spread operator "*"`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs)

```
val eqPOIIdExpressions = arrayOf(eq(get(KEY_ID), "134"))

// The * operator below converts the Array<Expression> into varargs for any
// see https://proandroiddev.com/kotlins-vararg-and-spread-operator-4200c07d65e1

switchCase(
    any(*eqPOIIdExpressions), appearanceIfSelected,
    appearanceIfNotSelected
)
```

Once I got that working, I went ahead and added all the array elements:

```
val eqPOIIdExpressions = pois!!.map {
    eq(get(KEY_ID), it.id)
}.toTypedArray()
```